# Response to an answer: Solution to maxMirror problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, rags-to-riches

[Garrett Openshaw](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35211/garrett-openshaw) had an okay answer to [Codingbat maxMirror challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39551/18427)

But there were a couple of issues with the code he gave, so I decided to review it and make it a little bit better.

I don't have access to Java here at work so I instead changed the code in C# which wasn't too much trouble.

I added a `List<int[]>` to keep track of all the test cases and added an extra loop to the outside of the the rest of the code.

I moved some variables as I mentioned in my comment to Garret's answer, and also moved some variables to the correct scope.  It seems like there should be more I can do to simplify this answer.

There was indentation and bracketing issues that made it difficult to read that I also changed.

```
List<int[]> sequences = new List<int[]> { 
     new int[] {1, 2, 1, 2, 1},
     new int[] {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1},
     new int[] {1, 2, 1, 4},
     new int[] {7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1}
 };

foreach (var sequence in sequences)
{
    int maxLength = 1;
    int endIndex = sequence.Length - 1;
    for (int frontIndex = 0; frontIndex < endIndex; frontIndex++)
    {
        for (int i = endIndex; i > frontIndex; i--)
        {
           if (sequence[frontIndex] == sequence[i])
            {
                var currentLength = 0;
                while (frontIndex + currentLength < sequence.Length && i - currentLength >= 0)
                {
                    if (sequence[frontIndex + currentLength] == sequence[i - currentLength])
                    {
                        currentLength++;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                if (currentLength > maxLength) 
                { 
                    maxLength = currentLength; 
                }                            
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Max length is " + maxLength);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is looking very good.

First thing I would do is split out a method, `GetMaxMirror`, and rename `maxLength` to `maxMirror`. Then I would put braces around the `break`, maybe invert the condition `if (sequence[frontIndex] == sequence[i])` to reduce nesting, and call it a day.

Ah, whoops, this fails on an empty array by returning the answer 1. Fix, add a unit test, and now we're really done.

Until... I notice that the complexity looks like it's \$O(n^3)\$. Let's increment a counter in the inner `while`:

```
while (frontIndex + currentLength < sequence.Length && i - currentLength >= 0)
{
    steps++;
    ...
```

And run it on our test cases:

```
GetMaxMirror took 15 steps.
Max length is 5
GetMaxMirror took 9 steps.
Max length is 3
GetMaxMirror took 3 steps.
Max length is 3
GetMaxMirror took 7 steps.
Max length is 2
```

Not bad!

And after a bit of playing around, we find that it runs badly on this input

```
private static int[] GetBadInput(int length)
{
    var result = new int[length];
    result[length / 2 - 1] = 1;
    return result;
}
```

Now let's run it again:

```
sequences.Add(GetBadInput(1000));
sequences.Add(GetBadInput(2000));
sequences.Add(GetBadInput(3000));

GetMaxMirror took 104664252 steps.
Max length is 999
GetMaxMirror took 835328502 steps.
Max length is 1999
GetMaxMirror took -1477974544 steps.
Max length is 2999
```

Ahhhh... integer overflow in our counter? Not good.

So what can we do? Let's look at the problem statement again.

> We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous
>   elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in
>   reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in `{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1}` is length 3 (the `{1, 2, 3}` part). Return the size of the
>   largest mirror section found in the given array.

So we're looking for the *longest contiguous sequence that appears in the input, and its reversal*. This sounds like another problem, [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) (LCS).

In particular,

$$
maxMirror(S) = LCS(S, T)
$$

where \$T\$ is \$S\$ reversed. If we can solve LCS, then we have a solution to `maxMirror`. Using dynamic programming, we can solve LCS in \$O(n^2)\$ time, with \$O(n)\$ space.

The pseudocode in that article is pretty good, so let's translate that to C#:

```
private static int GetMaxMirrorLcs(int[] sequence)
{
    var length = sequence.Length;
    var prevRow = new int[length];

    var maxMirror = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var row = new int[length];
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (sequence[i] != sequence[length - j - 1])
            {
                continue;
            }

            row[j] = (i == 0 || j == 0)
                ? 1
                : prevRow[j - 1] + 1;
            maxMirror = Math.Max(maxMirror, row[j]);
        }

        prevRow = row;
    }

    return maxMirror;
}
```

Since we split out our method before, it's easy to test that these give the same results:

```
foreach (var sequence in sequences)
{
    int maxMirror = GetMaxMirror(sequence);
    int maxMirrorLcs = GetMaxMirrorLcs(sequence);
    if (maxMirror != maxMirrorLcs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Answers don't match!");
        Console.WriteLine("Input: [{0}].", string.Join(", ", sequence));
        Console.WriteLine("GetMaxMirror: {0}. GetMaxMirrorLcs: {1}.", maxMirror, maxMirrorLcs);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am definitely going to have to ponder this code for a while and write a follow up to this question. You got me thinking about taking a pattern and then reverse and check the ending, but it is going to be a little more complicated than that.  it's going to be fun for sure!  something I am going to have to try at home while I am waiting for more bids on the freelance site I use.